# How to get element/component name using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a webpage that contains ASP.NET panels and JavaScript that gets all of the components in the page:

```
var items = Sys.Application.getComponents();
```

I need to get the name/ID of each of the elements in the items variable. I have tried the following code: (but it doesn't work)

```
for (var item in items) 
{
      alert(item.name);
}
```

What attribute of 'item' contains the name/ID? How can I modify the above code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `get_name()` and `get_id()` functions instead.

```
var items = Sys.Application.getComponents() ;
for( var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    var item = items[i];
    var id   = item.get_id();
    var name = item.get_name();
}
```

http://ajax.asp.net/docs/ClientReference/Sys/ApplicationClass/SysApplicationGetComponentsMethod.aspx

Comment: It displays 'CollapsiblePanelBehaviour', how can I get the ID of the panels it's iterating over in the for loop?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser: Have you tried `item.get_id()` as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

None. `item` is the key/property so you want `items[item].name`.

However, if `items` is an array, using `for..in` to iterate over it is completely inappropriate. In this case use `for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)` and `var item = items[i]` inside the loop body.

Comment: That displays [object object] and not the ID of each panel